# Poisson Distribution when only given using mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm doing the following homework problem and am unsure of whether or not my answers are correct. This is my first time working with Poisson distribution and I want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

> Suppose that the number of drivers who travel between a particular origin and destination during a designated time period has a Poisson distribution with mean $u = 20$. What is the probability that the number of drivers will
>
> a. Be at most 10?
>
> b. Exceed 20?
>
> c. Be between 10 and 20, inclusive? Be strictly between 10 and 20?
>
> d. Be within 2 standard deviations of the mean value?

I'm pretty much just trying to follow the formula that I was given for Poisson distribution and have the following answers:

a. $P(x\le 10) = \sum{0\to10}\frac {e^{20} \times 20^x}{x!} $

b. $P(x>20) = \frac {e^{20} \times 20^(20)}{20!} $

c. $P(10 \le x \le 20) = \sum_{10\to20}\frac {e^{20} \times 20^x}{x!} $

$P(10 < x <20) = \sum_{10\to20}\frac {e^{20} \times 20^x}{x!} $

d. not sure still

Answer (score 1):

The Poisson with parameter $\lambda$ has mean $\lambda$ (and variance $\lambda$).

So if you know the mean, you know the parameter.

For the first question, the required probability is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{10} e^{-20} \frac{20^k}{k!}.$$
Note that it is $e^{-20}$, not the $e^{20}$ of the post. The same mistake recurs.

For the probability that $X\gt 20$, we could sum from $21$ to $\infty$. But that's a long sum! To evaluate it, calculate the probability that $X\le 20$, and subtract this from $1$.

For c), your sum (apart from the fact that we need $e^{-20}$) is correct. For *strictly between*, sum from $11$ to $19$.

For d), the standard deviation is $\sqrt{20}$. So $2$ standard deviations is about $8.944$. Find the integers that are within $8.944$ of $20$, and take the sum of the Poisson probabilities in that range.

Comment: So for part d are you saying just to use the formula for Poisson going from 9 to 20? I'm not sure if I completely understood what you meant

Comment: Yea this explanation for D is very unclear.

Comment: The Poisson parameter $\lambda$ has variance $\lambda$, so SD $\sqrt{\lambda}$, here $\sqrt{20}$.  So $2$ SD is $2\sqrt{20}$, about $8.944$. That puts us in the range $11.05$  to $28.944$. Now find the sum of the Poisson probabilities $e^{-20}\frac{20^k}{k!}$, $k=12$ to $28$, though a case might be made for $k=11$ to $29$. Alternately, we could treat the Poisson with parameter $20$ as "close enough" to a normal, and use the normal approximation. The probability of being within $2$ SD units, for the normal, is very close to $0.95$, so for this Poisson we would expect roughly $0.95$.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite

(a) You have a missing sign in the exponential, so $$P(X \le 10) = \sum_{x=0}^{10} e^{-20}\frac{20^x}{x!}$$

(b) You could do a sum from $21$ to infinity but it is probably easier to consider $P(X \gt 20) = 1- P(X \le 20)$ and adapt the answer to (a)

(c) again you have a missing sign in the exponential, and for the strictly part the $\le$ have to become $\lt$.

(d) as a hint, the variance of a Poisson distribution is equal to its mean, and the standard deviation is the square root of the variance.